# currently learning Django and keep getting this error wheni try to runserver

Tags: python, django

i am a beginner learning using a tutorial. but i keep getting an error that isnt letting me move forward. I have attached an image with the full message
[ImportError: cannot import name 'Path' from 'django.urls' (C:\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\urls_*init*_.py)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXt82.png)

Comment: Please don't upload images of code, paste code instead, see how do I ask a good question [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Use "path" instead of "Path" in urls.py and . It should look like this -

```
from django.urls import path
```